# Excel VBA - Vlookup & range

Tags: excel, vba

I defined `Cl` as range and try to assign the range from the data in a table using `VLookUp`.

The result obtained from `VLookUp` is a range address (Example: `e58`).

I am unable to assign it as a range.

```
Set Cl= Range ("=vlookup(i, Range("a7:b28"), 2, False)")
```

Comment: this question does not make sense, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you run a formula in VBA.  Some functions are available in the `Application` object (including `VLookUp`).

```
Set cl = Range(Application.VLookup(i, Range("a7:b28"), 2, False))
```

For others use the `Application.WorksheetFunction` object

```
Set cl = Range(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(i, Range("a7:b28"), 2, False))
```

Note: there are some subtle differences in the two approaches, notably on how the functions handle errors.  Ant yes, you should add error handling to your code.

Side note: even if your approach did work, you would need to delimit the `"`'s around `a7:b28`, like this

```
"=vlookup(i, Range(""a7:b28""), 2, False)"
```